# How to convert stream data which come over udp to video device?

Tags: devices, udp, gstreamer

I'm trying to share my computer's camera with the remote computer. In order to do this, I wanted to share my own computer's camera with the udp port(stream), take the stream on the remote computer and put it on the virtual camera. So I thought I could use my own camera on platforms like google meet with my remote computer.

My application steps are as follows;

I started camera stream from local pc (`/dev/video0`) with use gstream udpsink and I could get stream data on remote pc like below:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e -v udpsrc port=5001 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec !  autovideosink
```

I created a virtual camera on the remote pc like below:

`sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 video_nr=3 card_label="VirtualCAM"`

At this point, I want to convert this stream data to video device. I tried to use `v4l2sink device=/dev/video5` instead of `autovideosink` but I got some error.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: It is hard to see what you tried, and what went wrong. My only thought is why are you  trying to send a stream via UDP?

Comment: I'm trying to share my computer's camera with the remote computer. That' all. In order to do this, I wanted to share my own computer's camera with the udp port(stream), take the stream on the remote computer and put it on the virtual camera. So I thought I could use my own camera on platforms like google meet with my remote computer.

Comment: Put clarifications in the question. So that the question is in one place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not convert the video stream using GStreamer. But ffmpeg works for me. I started sending and receiving video streams using Ffmpeg for both remote and local machines.

For Local Linux Machine:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f mpegts udp://<ip>:<port>
```

For Remote Linux Machine

```
ffmpeg -i udp://<ip>:<port> -f v4l2 /dev/video3
```

NOTE: /dev/video3 is a virtual camera on the remote machine